# UISwipeGesture not registering first swipe

Tags: swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Here's my code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
//add a swipe gesture
let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotateDial(_:)))
downSwipe.direction = .down
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
```

The first time I swipe down it doesn't recognize the gesture. I read in another SO that the swipe gesture is registering itself on the first swipe. How do I fix that?

Comment: I tried your exact same code and it works.. Yours may not be getting called due to an interfering gestures coming from another UI Controls like UiTableView or any other gesture you may have added.

Comment: Thanks, there's an imageView overlaying parts of the UIViewController but it is not set up for userInteraction.